# form redirect error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have nearly two identical codes
The first one which wraps the comment in a url shortener  works but the second one doesn't. Is there a way of making the second one work without the url shortener?

```
<script>
function go(){
    var uri = 'http://on.fb.me/UfEQM2' 
        + encodeURIComponent('');;

    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = 
        '<form target="_parent" method="post" action="' 
        + uri 
        + '"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit();
}    
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"> </iframe>
```

and

```
<script>
function go(){
    var uri = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=http://google.com?0reghre' 
        + encodeURI('');;

    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = 
        '<form target="_parent" method="post" action="' 
        + uri 
        + '"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit();
}    
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"> </iframe>?
```

Comment: You're using encodeURIComponent() in the first example and encodeURI() in the second example. Did you intend to do that?

Comment: cine they are empty they don't matter. accidental

Comment: No, not accidental. You follow both with two semi-colons which could also be causing a problem.